# FullCalendar jquery Render Event Text Color

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am totally new at programming in any web languages so please be patient.

I have downloaded and implemented FullCalendar by Adam Shaw. I have implemented event background colors based on a color field in my recordset. The problem I am having is my text color for the events is white and does not show up well against the light colored background. I believe this color is set in this link

```
 //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.min.css
```

Can I override this on my render function? If so can you please give me a little help. If not maybe you can point me in the right direction. I have looked at the fullCalendar documentation and many post on here and I am clueless.

Here is what I currently have in my event render function. Thanks for looking.

```
eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
  if (event.color) {
    element.css('background-color', event.color);
  }
  element.qtip({
    content: {
      text: qTipText(event.start, event.end, event.description),
      title: '<strong>' + event.title + '</strong>'
    },
    position: {
      my: 'bottom left',
      at: 'top right'
    },
    style: { classes: 'qtip-shadow qtip-rounded' }
  });
}
```

Comment: you can set the colours for all events via https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventColor/ and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventBackgroundColor/ and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventTextColor/ and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventBorderColor/, or set them within the event JSON data on a per-event basis - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/ or a per-event-source basis - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Source_Object/. No need to use eventRender to control this (although you can by setting CSS properties)

Comment: I guess I am more of a novice than you realize. I read all of the documentation and just don't know where to add the code needed to change the event color. I read somewhere this could be done in my json file. This is what it looks like. Again, I don't even know where to start. Thanks for looking. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Well there are 3 places you can do it, as I outlined above - "globally" in the fullCalendar options (so it applies to all events), or on a per-event basis in the JSON, or - if you use event sources - on a per-event-source basis, in the event source options. It depends what you want / need to do. Do some events have different colours to others, or are they all going to be the same?

Comment: I want all events to have a black text color. Thanks

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventTextColor/ - set that in your fullCalendar options, then. (i.e. when you initialise the calendar, so like `$("#calendar").fullCalendar({ eventTextColor: "#000"` ....etc

Comment: So in my event render I put in eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
            //alert(event.title);
            eventTextColor: 'red'

Comment: oops I hit enter prior to cleaning it up.. sorry

Comment: and tried eventTextColor = 'red'

Comment: Ok let me take a step back. When you say "globally in the full calendar options. Are we working with "calendarscript.js" at this point?

Comment: Will this line override what I am trying to do? "theme: true,"

Comment: I gave you the example above already of how you set it. Don't you have some code like that in your page somewhere? If not, how do you create the fullCalendar? It's the same options list in which you declare the eventRender

Comment: Thanks for being patient. I tried the above by changing $('#calendar').fullCalendar({     to    $("#calendar").fullCalendar({ eventTextColor: "#000"     You did say to set it in my options, I don't know where to do that. I feel like an idiot but I hate giving up.

Comment: Can you show the whole of your calendar code please - i.e. particularly the bits surrounding the "eventRender" code which you shared already.

Comment: BTW according to the fullCalendar theme demo at https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.8.2/demos/themes.html, the Cupertino theme works just fine. Event text is white, event backgrounds are dark blue. Are you sure you haven't got some other CSS (or customised your theme CSS) which is interfering with this (e.g. by overriding the same style definitions)?

Comment: Very trivially, here is a working example using the cupertino theme: http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/248/ . And here is an example, still using that theme, where I've used the "eventTextColor" option to change the text colour of all events to a red colour: http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/251/

Comment: After reading this over and over I decided to re-download the fullCalendar, what I discovered is a mismatch in the code I downloaded vs the code I am using. I sincerely apologize for wasting your time. I am using the full calendar implementation by esau silva  I would still like to change the text color as the process should be similar? If you can take a quick look at my code I have posted it here https://github.com/ohiogto1969/ASP.Net-EventCalendar2   Thank you very much

Comment: Well I don't know what modifications that package makes, but assuming it merely adds some server-side functionality, and doesn't alter the fullCalendar stock package, then you can still use all the different options I mentioned in the first comment.

Comment: You are a very patient man, it now works! When I was adding eventTextColor: "#000", to my script I was using single quotes, that coupled with chrome toggling my "disable cache feature" was cauing issues. I thank you so very much!

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working.